# How to extract last part in PHP?

Tags: php

This would be an example:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/redirect.php&q=dynamic_word">redirect</a>
```

**dynamic_word** can be changed because it is dynamic. When click "redirect", **dynamic_word** will be extracted. So, how to extract it in redirect.php file ? Thanks !

Comment: @jeroen, It is not possible. My problem is different.

Comment: Is the address a URL or part of your script?

Comment: If your problem is so different, and $_GET doesn't work, then perhaps you should explain your problem in detail

Comment: @jeff HI, it is address a URL

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET  to get parameters from an URL

```
   <?php

    $thatName = $_GET['q'];

    echo $thatName;
```

Result

```
dynamic_word
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work. It show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If samitha's correct looking answer is incorrect then perhaps you mean you would like to extract the dynamic word from a string.

In that case you could do

```
<?php

$string = 'http://mywebsite.com/redirect.php&q=dynamic_word';

$ex_stirng = explode('&q=', $string);

$dynamic_word = $ex_string(1);

?>
```

Or even use the **strstr** function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: Thanks, http://mywebsite.com/redirect.php&q=dynamic_word is address URL. Can you show me how to get it, please ?

Comment: You have been given three solutions. Unless you explain what you are trying to do in more detail I don't think you're going to receive any more help :-S